# Помогите разобраться с font-face local()

Tags: css

Увидел вот такой код подключения шрифтов

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c";
    src: local('fonts/Rounded Mplus 1c ExtraBold'), local('RoundedMplus1c-ExtraBold'), 
    url('fonts/Roundedmplus1c.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fonts/Roundedmplus1c.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/Roundedmplus1c.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 800;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Не понимаю почему в первом local() стоит "fonts/" и как разработчик понял, что далее нужно писать именно **Rounded Mplus 1c ExtraBold**, ведь в семействе шрифтов написано  *font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c";* Почему не **M PLUS Rounded 1c ExtraBold?**

Далее идёт local('RoundedMplus1c-ExtraBold'),  помимо того что не понятно зачем выше local с fonts/ было задано. Теперь и тут похожий вопрос. Где разработчик взял информацию, что нужно написать было именно ***'RoundedMplus1c-ExtraBold'*** а не "M PLUS Rounded 1c-Extra Bold" . Ведь в font-family написано  "M PLUS Rounded 1c";

Comment: А этот код точно работает?

Comment: неправильный? Тут в таком стиле все шрифты были добавлены. url('fonts/Roundedmplus1c.woff2') format('woff2'), итд я так понимаю работает, а вот local неправильный что ли

Comment: Я не знаю, правильный или нет.